# Reading numbers after a keyword, and using only certain numbers from the list

Tags: python

I would like to have my Python code read numbers following a keyword such as 'OUTPUT', all the way to the end of the .dat file that I'm working with. However, all the numbers wouldn't have to be read by the program.. just numbers that are attributed to a position on the .dat file. For example, this is somewhat what my file looks like:

```
VARIABLES= "a", "b", "c", "d" , "e", "f", "g"
OUTPUT= 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
...
```

and I would like to only read and work with the numbers attributed to a, d, and g(all the way down to the end of the document).
For instance, the expected output for these three lines would be 1, 4, 7. & 8, 
11, 14 & 15, 18, 21.

I've already tried a few different approaches to this problem, but none seem to work out too well for me. The closest I've gotten to solving this problem is with the code down below:

```
with open('C:/Users/filename', "r") as input:
    for line in input:
        if line.startswith('OUTPUT'):
           print(next(input), end='')
           continue
           break
```

The problem with this code is that I'm only able to read the first line of code following "OUTPUT", and nothing else. I'm also not able to figure out how to read only the numbers related to the three specific letters. 
Please let me know how I might solve this problem, or give me some code that works better than what I have now!

thank you!!

Comment: What does it mean for a number to be "attributed to" a letter?

Comment: I'm not understanding the second part of the question regarding "numbers related to the three specific letters". Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: Your intended control flow is unclear.  `ZONE` doesn't appear in your input or your description.  `continue` insures that you can never reach the `break` ... and since the `continue` is at the bottom of the loop, it does nothing.

Comment: Also, there's no apparent attempt to extract individual numbers from the line.  I suggest that you work through tutorials on the appropriate topics: loops, file handling, and input processing.

Comment: yes, sorry. For instance for the three lines above, the output should be: 1, 4, 7. 8,11,14. and 15, 18, 21

Comment: I incorrectly posted the code snippet. It should not be "ZONE". It should be OUTPUT. I will edit the post to reflect that

Comment: It does not change anything. How can we know that number are related to the "a" letter ?

Comment: In the .dat output file which is created by a  software, 1, 8, and 15 are all outputs coming from that 'a' variable. Each number you see is an output of one of those variables and each variable outputs a number (a= every first number... g=every seventh number)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know the variables/letters and already know that you want data from a,d,g (or 0,3,6th element):

```
with open('C:/Users/filename', "r") as input:
    start_print=False
    output=[]
    for line in input:
        if start_print:
           output.extend([line.split()[i] for i in [0,3,6]])
        if line.startswith('OUTPUT'):
            start_print=True
    print(','.join(output))
```

OUTPUT:

```
1,4,7,8,11,14,15,18,21
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses itemgetter to get the indexes from the wanted columns (which letters you need to supply to the program).

EDIT: I guess the wanted columns may contain more than one letter, (a,b,c,...), so the solution would need modified to account for that - I'll try to post a modified solution)

EDIT: Modified the solution to account for multiple letters

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter

file = """\
VARIABLES= "a", "b", "c", "d" , "e", "f", "g"
OUTPUT= 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
8 9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21 
""".splitlines()

idx = []
found = False
wanted = ('a', 'd', 'g')

for line in file:
    if line.startswith('VARIABLES'):
        #var = re.findall('[a-z]+', line)
        _, *var = re.split(r'\W+', line)
        for letter in wanted:
            idx.append(var.index(letter))

        get_indexes = itemgetter(*idx)

    elif line.startswith('OUTPUT'):
        found = True

    elif found:
        data = line.split()
        print(' '.join(get_indexes(data)), end=' ')
```

Prints:

```
1 4 7 8 11 14 15 18 21
```